How to manually calculate marginal effects from output of a multinomial logistic regression
I need to calculate marginal effects based on coefficients from a mutlinomial logistic regression
Here is some toy R code (apologies users of other software but concepts translate across platforms so feel free to ignore all but output)
# read in data
ml <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")

The data set contains variables on 200 students. The outcome variable is prog, program type, a three-level categorical variable (general, academic, vocation). The predictor variable is social economic status, ses, a three-level categorical variable, with low, middle, and high. To make this example simpler we will remove middle category, so it is just low and high SES. We also need to make academic the reference level (just to make it consistent with the oarc web page). Apologies for calling the tidyverse suite, but I think it easier than calling all the individual packages.
library(tidyverse)
library(nnet)
ml %<>%
  select(id, ses, prog) %>%
    filter(ses != "middle") %>%
      mutate(ses = fct_drop(ses),
             prog = fct_relevel(prog, "academic"))

The model is very simple to run using the multinom function from the nnet package
test_nnet <- multinom(prog ~ ses,
                      data = ml)

summary(test_nnet)

# output
# Coefficients:
#          (Intercept)   seshigh
# general   -0.1718492 -1.368592
# vocation  -0.4595337 -1.332220

If we consider our coefficients from the first row to be $b_1$ and our coefficients from the second row to be $b_2$, we can write our model equations as
$ln \left( \frac{P(prog = general)}{P(prog = academic)} \right) = b_{10} + b_{11}(ses=2)$
and
$ln \left( \frac{P(prog = vocation)}{P(prog = academic)} \right) = b_{20} + b_{21}(ses=2)$
Now from what I gather $b_{10}$ is intercept for the low-ses group, which is the log-odds of a low ses student selecting the general course compared to the academic course, which is $-0.17$. $b_{11}$ is the difference in log-odds between the high- and low-ses groups in log-odds of selecting the general course compared to the academic course, which is $-1.37$. The corresponding logic works for the vocational compared to the academic course.
From these coefficients (I think) we can construct log-odds of each 'cell' in this 2 x 2 matrix in the usual way
$Log\text{-}odds_{low\text{-}ses/generalvsacademic} = -0.17$
$Log\text{-}odds_{high\text{-}ses/generalvsacademic} = -0.17 + -1.37 = -1.54$
$Log\text{-}odds_{low\text{-}ses/vocationalvsacademic} = -0.46$
$Log\text{-}odds_{high\text{-}ses/vocationalvsacademic} = -0.46 + -1.33 = -1.79$
But say I wanted to obtain the marginal effect of ses within each level ofprog? (e.g. this graph)

Russ Lenth's emmeans package allows us to obtain estimates of these marginal effects relatively simply with the following code
# run for the emmeans grid
em_nnet <- emmeans(test_nnet,
                   specs = ~ses|prog)

The default output gives us the coefficients as probabilities, which is fine, but I need log-odds. For this we use the regrid() function.
em_nnet_logit <- regrid(em_nnet,
                        transform = "logit") 

em_nnet_logit

# output

# prog = academic:
# ses    prob    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# low  -0.388 0.297  4   -1.213    0.437
# high  0.965 0.294  4    0.149    1.781
#
# prog = general:
# ses    prob    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# low  -0.661 0.308  4   -1.516    0.193
# high -1.695 0.363  4   -2.701   -0.688
#
# prog = vocation:
# ses    prob    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# low  -1.070 0.335  4   -1.999   -0.142
# high -1.986 0.403  4   -3.105   -0.867

And we pass this grid of log-odds estimates for each of the 2 x 3 = 6 possible events (seslow-academic, seshigh-academic, seslow_general, seshigh_general, seslow_vocational, seshigh_vocational) into the pairs() function
pairs_logit <- confint(pairs(em_nnet_logit, reverse = TRUE))

pairs_logit

# output
# prog = academic:
# contrast   estimate    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# high - low    1.353 0.418  4    0.193    2.513
#
# prog = general:
# contrast   estimate    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# high - low   -1.033 0.476  4   -2.354    0.288
#
# prog = vocation:
# contrast   estimate    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
# high - low   -0.915 0.524  4   -2.370    0.539
#
# Results are given on the log odds ratio (not the response) scale.

Unfortunately, for reasons I won't go into here I need to calculate these marginal effects manually as log-odds coefficients. My question is, how do we get from the regression coefficients to these estimated marginal effects? or rather is it possible to use the coefficients from the regression output to manually calculate these simple effects?
If it were a Gaussian regression I could calculate these conditional effects via the regression output, but I have much less experience with the multinomial logistic. Unfortunately I am not a biostatistician so the maths is beyond my abilities.

In a three-outcome, multinomial logit (with category 1 as the base):
$$
\begin{align}
\mathtt{Pr}(y=1 \mid \mathtt{SES}) = \frac{1}{\exp(0)+ \exp(\alpha_2 + \beta_2\cdot \mathtt{high})+\exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3\cdot \mathtt{high})} \\
\mathtt{Pr}(y=2 \mid \mathtt{SES}) = \frac{\exp(\alpha_2 + \beta_2 \cdot \mathtt{high})}{\exp(0)+ \exp(\alpha_2 + \beta_2\cdot \mathtt{high})+\exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3\cdot \mathtt{high})} \\
\mathtt{Pr}(y=3 \mid \mathtt{SES}) = \frac{\exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3 \cdot \mathtt{high})}{\exp(0)+ \exp(\alpha_2 + \beta_2\cdot \mathtt{high})+\exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3\cdot \mathtt{high})} \\
\end{align}$$
where $\mathtt{high} \in \{0,1\}$. Here $1$ is academic, $2$ is general, and $3$ is vocational. For example, the vocational outcome coefficients are $\alpha_3 = -0.4595337$ and $\beta_3 = -1.332220$. Since the base is 1, you have set $\alpha_1 = \beta_1=0$, so $\exp(0+0)=\exp(0)=1$. This normalization is why the academic equation looks different.
Since you have no other covariates, you can get the marginal effects on the probability scale by calculating the three finite differences:
$$
\begin{align}
ME_1 = \mathtt{Pr}(y=1 \mid \mathtt{high=1}) - \mathtt{Pr}(y=1 \mid \mathtt{high=0}) \\
ME_2 =\mathtt{Pr}(y=2 \mid \mathtt{high=1}) - \mathtt{Pr}(y=2 \mid \mathtt{high=0}) \\
ME_3 = \mathtt{Pr}(y=3 \mid \mathtt{high=1}) - \mathtt{Pr}(y=3 \mid \mathtt{high=0})  \\
\end{align}$$
From eyeballing your graph, the SES effect for vocational should be approximately $ME_3 = (0.12 - 0.25) = -0.13$, a decrease in the probability of choosing a vocational program of $13$ percentage points.
A good sanity check that you did the math right is $ME_1 + ME_2 + ME_3 = 0$. Even though you change the probabilities by varying SES, the new probabilities still have to sum to one, so the effects must cancel out.
Here's the R Code to implement this:
# Load necessary libraries
# Uncomment the following lines to install the required packages if not already installed
# install.packages("foreign")   # For reading data in Stata format
# install.packages("nnet")      # For fitting multinomial logistic regression models
# install.packages("tidyverse") # For data manipulation and visualization
# install.packages("emmeans")   # For estimated marginal means (emmeans) and pairwise comparisons

library(foreign)   # For reading data in Stata format (.dta files)
library(nnet)      # For fitting multinomial logistic regression models (using multinom)
library(tidyverse) # For data manipulation (using dplyr) and visualization (using ggplot2)
library(emmeans)   # For calculating estimated marginal means (emmeans) and performing pairwise comparisons

# Load the dataset from the specified URL
ml <- read.dta("https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/stat/data/hsbdemo.dta")

# Data manipulation
ml %<>%  # Use the magrittr pipe (%<>) to update the 'ml' object in place
  select(id, ses, prog) %>%   # Select only the 'id', 'ses', and 'prog' columns from the dataset
  filter(ses != "middle") %>% # Remove rows where 'ses' (socioeconomic status) is "middle"
  mutate(
    ses = fct_drop(ses),      # Drop unused factor levels in 'ses' (after filtering)
    prog = fct_relevel(prog, "academic") # Relevel 'prog' (program type) to have "academic" as the reference level
  )

# Fit a multinomial logistic regression model
test_nnet <- multinom(prog ~ ses, data = ml) # Model 'prog' as a function of 'ses'
summary(test_nnet) # Display the summary of the fitted model (coefficients, standard errors, etc.)

# (A) Calculate estimated marginal means (emmeans) for the fitted model
em_nnet <- emmeans(test_nnet, specs = ~ses | prog) # Calculate emmeans for each level of 'ses' within each level of 'prog'

em_nnet # Display the estimated marginal means

# Calculate pairwise comparisons with confidence intervals on the response scale
pairs_logit <- confint(pairs(em_nnet, reverse = TRUE)) # Calculate pairwise comparisons of the emmeans and obtain confidence intervals

# Display the pairwise comparisons with confidence intervals
pairs_logit

# (B) Repeat Above By Hand
# Extract coefficients from the model summary
coefficients <- summary(test_nnet)$coefficients

# Calculate predicted probabilities for high SES
p_aca_high <- exp(0) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["general", "seshigh"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["vocation", "seshigh"]))
p_gen_high <- exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["general", "seshigh"]) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["general", "seshigh"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["vocation", "seshigh"]))
p_voc_high <- exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["vocation", "seshigh"]) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["general", "seshigh"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["vocation", "seshigh"]))

# Calculate predicted probabilities for low SES
p_aca_low <- exp(0) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"]))
p_gen_low <- exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"]) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"]))
p_voc_low <- exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"]) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"]))

# Calculate differences in predicted probabilities between high and low SES
d_aca <- p_aca_high - p_aca_low # Difference in probability for academic program
d_gen <- p_gen_high - p_gen_low # Difference in probability for general program
d_voc <- p_voc_high - p_voc_low # Difference in probability for vocational program

# Display the calculated finite differences
d_aca
d_gen
d_voc

# Compare With (A)
pairs_logit

The tail of the output should look like this:
 # Display the calculated finite differences
> d_aca
[1] 0.3198817
> d_gen
[1] -0.185253
> d_voc
[1] -0.1346286
> 
> # Compare With (A)
> pairs_logit
prog = academic:
 contrast   estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 high - low    0.320 0.0926  4   0.0629   0.5769

prog = general:
 contrast   estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 high - low   -0.185 0.0839  4  -0.4182   0.0477

prog = vocation:
 contrast   estimate     SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 high - low   -0.135 0.0766  4  -0.3474   0.0782

Confidence level used: 0.95 

The marginal effects do add up to zero, and the "by-hand" method matches the output from emmeans.

To replicate the log OR differences you calculated instead of the ME on the probabilities that I had above, use:
log_or_diff_gen <- log(p_gen_high/(1 - p_gen_high)) - log(p_gen_low/(1 - p_gen_low))
log_or_diff_aca <- log(p_aca_high/(1 - p_aca_high)) - log(p_aca_low/(1 - p_aca_low))
log_or_diff_voc <- log(p_voc_high/(1 - p_voc_high)) - log(p_voc_low/(1 - p_voc_low))

log_or_diff_gen
log_or_diff_aca
log_or_diff_voc 


Hi @Dimitry. This is fantastic! I am at work now but will go over your code in the next 48 hours and be back with questions (probably:). I will not award the bounty now but I'm quite sure you will get it. Just quickly, I assume the differences between ses levels at each level of prog are differences in probability? How would you get each 'cellcoefficient (e.g.p_aca_high, p_gen_low`) expressed as log-odds?

Let's focus on the vocational outcome as an example:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\mathtt{Pr}(y=1 \mid \mathtt{high}=1)}{\mathtt{Pr}(y=3 \mid \mathtt{high}=1)}  & = \frac{\frac{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta_1)}{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta_1\cdot \mathtt{high})+\exp(0)+ \exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3)}}{\frac{\exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3 \cdot \mathtt{high})}{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta_1\cdot \mathtt{high})+\exp(0)+ \exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3)}} \
&= \frac{\exp(\alpha_1 + \beta_1)}{\exp(\alpha_3 + \beta_3)} \
& = \exp(\alpha_1 + \beta_1 - \alpha_3  - \beta_3) \
\end{align}
$$

The left-hand side are the odds of general to vocational. Taking natural logs of both sides, gets you:
$$ \ln \left( \frac{\mathtt{Pr}(y=1 \mid \mathtt{high}=1)}{\mathtt{Pr}(y=3 \mid \mathtt{high}=1)} \right) = (\alpha_1 + \beta_1) - (\alpha_3 + \beta_3).$$ This is just a simple difference of the mlogit coefficients. You can define the others in a similar fashion.

Personally, I think odds are for gamblers only and much harder to interpret correctly, but there is no arguing about tastes.

I agree, differences in probabilities are much easier to understand but, for better or worse, odds ratios are the lingua franca of academic research, in my field at least.

So in your code you calculated probabilities for each cell (e.g. p_aca_high <- exp(0) / (exp(0) + exp(coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["general", "seshigh"]) + exp(coefficients["vocation", "(Intercept)"] + coefficients["vocation", "seshigh"])). How would this equation change if you expressed it as log-odds instead of probabilities?

For the LO example above, $\alpha_1$ correspond to coefficients["general", "(Intercept)"] and $\beta_1$ corresponds to coefficients["general", "seshigh"], and so on.

Thank you so much Dimitry. I am still not clear what the equations would be for the log-odds versions of p_aca_high, p_gen_high, p_voc_high, p_aca_low, p_gen_low, and p_voc_low. Is there any way you could enlighten me by supplying the full equations? I tried simply removing all the anti-log terms but, for example, if I do that to the equations for p_aca_high it gives me a 0 in the numerator. Sorry for being clueless.

Just do arithmetic on the coefficients. Or maybe I am missing something. Can you clarify which odds ratio you have in mind?

I think you find 'just doing arithmetic' much easier than me :) The coefficients in the regression output are on the log-odds scale. You then (very helpfully) supplied equations in your code for the probabilities of each of the six possible 'events': aca-low, aca-high, gen-low, gen-high, voc-low, voc-high. But rather than the equations for the probabilities of each of these six events, I need the equations for the log-odds of these six events. Does that make sense? Sorry for not being more clear in previous comments.

Could I simply use your equations to get the probability of each event then convert that probability to log-odds via $ln \left( \frac{Pr_{event}}{1-Pr_{event}} \right)$?

Odds ratios are typically calculated relative to a single reference category at a time, not all other categories simultaneously. But if that's what you want and can interpret it, your approach should work.

See the addendum above for the exact code.

Great answer Dimitriy (+1)

Yes thank you so much @Dimitry. I'm doing a Bayesian version of this analysis in the brms() package, so needed a way to calculate the log-odds coefficients for each cell. I can now apply the method you describe to the mcmc chains for the four coefficients from the model. in order to yield chains of estimated marginal means.
